# How do you express the probability of outcomes for the next state in Markov chain (given some state)?

Tags: markov-chains, expected-value

How do you express the probability of outcomes for the next state in Markov chain (given some state)?

This is an expected value, i.e. suppose 5 states, then if one starts at state 4, then the "outcomes" from this are:

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k \mathbb{P}(f_1=k|f_0=4)$$

However, I have troubles, regarding, how is this expressed using the $\mathbb{E}(...)$ syntax?

Comment: So the $f_t$ are the states of the Markov chain at time $t$. What is $x_k$?

Comment: @kccu Some value that's attained at that state. So this models some kind of thing where every state "produces some value (which we are interested in)". Just like in ordinary expected value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case

Answer (score 1):

You are computing the expectation of some function of the Markov chain. Namely, $X_t = \sum_{k=1}^5 x_k 1\{f_t = k\}$. In this case, your expression is just $\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid f_0 = 4]$.

The way to obtain this is to write $\mathbb{P}(f_1=k\mid f_0=4)$ as $\mathbb{E}[1\{f_1=k\} \mid f_0=4]$ and use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote down is how the conditional expectation is defined.

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y] = \sum^n_{k=1} x_k\mathbb{P}(X = x_k | Y = y)$$